# Delete/Destroy and Edit routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, restful-url

I am new at Rails and am trying to build my own app for a project. I keep getting this error while trying to create a delete and edit.

> NameError in Listings#show

Here is my routes.rb file...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :listings

    root 'listings#home'

    get '/listings/new' => 'listings#new'

    post '/listings' => 'listings#create'

    get '/listings/:id' => 'listings#show'

    get '/listings/:id/edit' => 'listings#edit'

    patch '/listings/:id' => 'listings#update'

    delete '/listings/:id' => 'listings#destroy'

end


# Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
#     listings GET    /listings(.:format)          listings#index
#              POST   /listings(.:format)          listings#create
#  new_listing GET    /listings/new(.:format)      listings#new
# edit_listing GET    /listings/:id/edit(.:format) listings#edit
#      listing GET    /listings/:id(.:format)      listings#show
#              PATCH  /listings/:id(.:format)      listings#update
#              PUT    /listings/:id(.:format)      listings#update
#              DELETE /listings/:id(.:format)      listings#destroy
```

Here is my Listings Controller...

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_listing, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @listings = Listing.all
    end

    def show
        @listings = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @listings = Listing.new
    end

    def create
        @listings = Listing.new(listing_params)
            @listings.save
            redirect_to listings_path
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @listings.update(listing_params)
            redirect_to listings_path
        else
            render :edit
        end

    def destroy
        @listings = Listing.find(params[:id])
           redirect_to listings_url
    end

    def set_listing
        @listings = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    def listing_params
        params.require(:listing).permit(:address, :unit, :price, :description, :img_url)
    end

end
```

Here is my show.html.erb file...

```
<center><h2>Current Listing</h2></center>

<h4>Address:</h4> <h3><%= @listings.address %></h3>
<h4>Unit #:</h4> <h3><%= @listings.unit %></h3>
<h4>Price: $</h4> <h3><%= @listings.price %></h3>
<h4>Description:</h4> <h3><%= @listings.description %></h3>
<h4>Agent ID:</h4> <h3><%= @listings.agent_id %></h3>
<h4>Image:</h4> <h3><%= @listings.img_url %><p></h3>

<%= link_to 'Back', listings_path %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', listing, :method => 'delete' %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is most likely here:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', listing, :method => 'delete' %>
```

`listing` is not defined, you should use `@listings` which you defined in the controller.

Couple of other things:

1. `@listings` is extremely misleading name here. If it is a singular object, use singular form `@listing`. It will make your life much easier when you come back to this code in next year. Naturally, you should still use `@listings` when dealing with collections (index action).
2. You already have a method for doing what you do in show action - `set_listings`. Just add `show` to the list next to `before_action` to DRY your code.
3. `resources :listings` already created routes for all listings actions, there is no need to define them "manually".
4. Always, always, always look at (and publish in your questions) the full error message. It will give you much more idea of what happened. There are thousands of reasons why `NameError` can be raised. `nameError: undefined method listing for <ActionViev...>` narrows it down to just few, and your backtrace would narrow it down further to a point.

Answer (score 0):

Change Delete link to

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', listing_path(@listings),
            :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Remove following routes from routes.rb as `resources :listings` in routes file will provide those routes automatically

```
get '/listings/new' => 'listings#new'

post '/listings' => 'listings#create'

get '/listings/:id' => 'listings#show'

get '/listings/:id/edit' => 'listings#edit'

patch '/listings/:id' => 'listings#update'

delete '/listings/:id' => 'listings#destroy'
```